# Complex searching for tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I have currently have a problem with searching products with tags:

```
Products
id name
1  lightbulb

Tags
id name
1  energy
2  light
3  lights

Tagships
id taggable_id tag_id
1  1          1
1  1          2
1  1          3
```

I need to build a query to get the products that are tagged as (energy) and (light or lights)

So far this doesn't work:

```
SELECT ..<snipped>.. 
FROM `products` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tagships` 
ON (`products`.`id` = `tagships`.`taggable_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tags` 
ON (`tags`.`id` = `tagships`.`tag_id`) 
WHERE ((tags.name = 'energy' OR tags.name = 'energies') 
AND (tags.name = 'light' OR tags.name = 'lights')) 
GROUP BY products.id 
HAVING COUNT(tagships.tag_id) <= 2 
ORDER BY products.updated_at DESC
```

UPDATED the query.
Note: I need the query to search for singular and plural tense of the tag as seen in the above query.

Comment: I've updated my answer to accommodate finding plurals of your search terms. Unfortunately, English has too many plural forms to do it algorithmically; you'll have to just list all the terms you want to find. Perhaps you'll want to have a list of possible search terms with their corresponding plurals if you want to add value to your searches?

Answer (score 0):

try the following query:

```
SELECT ..<snipped>.. 
FROM `products` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tagships` 
ON (`products`.`id` = `tagships`.`taggable_id` 
AND `tagships`.`taggable_type` = 'Product') 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tags` 
ON (`tags`.`id` = `tagships`.`tag_id`) 
WHERE ((tags.name = 'energy' OR tags.name = 'energies') 
OR (tags.name = 'light' OR tags.name = 'lights')) 
GROUP BY products.id 
HAVING COUNT(tagships.tag_id) <= 2 
ORDER BY products.updated_at DESC
```

Comment: I actually need them to be singular AND plural. I can't put in 'energy%'.

Comment: then just the above query, you need to put `OR`

Comment: Sorr, but I don't see what change you did in your query. I can't use 'like' and if I replace `(tags.name like 'energy%') 
or (tags.name  like 'light%)` with `((tags.name = 'energy' OR tags.name = 'energies') 
AND (tags.name = 'light' OR tags.name = 'lights'))`, it would revert back to my query which doesn't work.

Comment: and using `((tags.name = 'energy' OR tags.name = 'energies') OR (tags.name = 'light' OR tags.name = 'lights'))` won't work because I need the product to both tags, `light` or `lights` AND `energy` or `energies`.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT distinct p.id, p.name
FROM products as p
join tagships as ts on ts.product_id = p.id
join tags as t on t.id = ts.tag_id
where t.name in ('energy', 'energies', 'light', 'lights');
```

I've used aliases to make the code more readable. Also you don't want outer joins, since you don't want records that don't match in the joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, a tag can't be `'energy'` or `'energies'` *and*, at the same time, `'light'` or `'lights'`. So, the condition in your query must consist of `OR`s only:

```
WHERE t.name = 'energy'
   OR t.name = 'energies'
   OR t.name = 'light'
   OR t.name = 'lights'
```

Alternatively, of course, you can use `IN`:

```
WHERE t.name IN ('energy', 'energies', 'light', 'lights')
```

Another thing is, how to check that a product has both at least one of the first two and at least one of the other two. I would probably do it using a `HAVING` clause like this:

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.name IN ('energy', 'energies') THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN t.name IN ('light', 'lights')    THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: You are correct on the first statement. but I can't use your first two queries. I will try your last query.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your *can't use*. I might not have made myself clear enough: the `HAVING` clause in my answer is supposed to be used with either of my `WHERE` clauses, not just as an alternative to them.